# Running matlab code at boot in Beaglebone

Tags: matlab, beagleboneblack

Currently, I am using beaglebone connected to PC and executing Matlab code.If I execute code in matlab then automatically it runs in Beaglebone as it connected to PC. But how to run Matlab code at boot? I know to put matlab code file in scrpits at boot.But, I have not seen any .m or a matlab file while executing in beaglebone to put in script file at boot.